# memory leak sql server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

can you help me, please.
*Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU3) (KB4458871) - 13.0.5216.0 (X64)   Sep 13 2018 22:16:01   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0  (Build 14393: )*

```
select
    sqlserver_start_time,
    physical_memory_kb/1024/1024 physical_memory_GB,
    committed_kb/1024/1024 committed_GB,
    committed_target_kb/1024/1024 committed_target_GB,
    visible_target_kb/1024/1024 visible_target_GB
    FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info(nolock)
```

physical_memory_GB = 1023   committed_GB = 796

When I opened task manager, I see than 1Tb in use, but i couldn't understood, where 227 Gb
I try to do
dbcc freepro... and other, but nothing happens.
I'l be glad your answers

Comment: You see 1 TB in use by the "SQL Server Windows NT - 64 bit" (MSSQLSERVER) Task? Are you sure this is the same server and not your local machine vs remote?

Comment: i see this in perfomace monitor on the remote server

Comment: @Ильдар What is your servers Min/Max server memory settings? On my system the committed memory value is the max memory setting of my SQL Server what memory has been committed to SQL Server and is different from the overall RAM utilisation of the system13.9GB actual usage from task manager vs. 11GB committed

Comment: 786432 min
1015808 max